# Valid syntax for autowired properties in spring

Tags: spring, properties, autowired

I have been looking for an explanation of how Spring Framework will look for @AutoWired properties. I have noticed that when using the hikariCP library that setting either of the properties below will result in a correct max pool size.

spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=3

or

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=3

Does Spring use both camel case and hyphen separated to lookup autowired properties?  Where might I find an explanation in the spring docs?

Answer (score 5):

That isn't a feature of the core [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework) but rather a feature of [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot).

Spring Boot has a feature called [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) which is used for properties mapped to a class annotated/used with `@ConfigurationProperties`. Each property that is being bound can be used with camel-case, dashes or even uppercase with dashes (generally used for environment variables!).

So all of these will work in the same way (the latter is often used to pass it as an environment or system variable).

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=3
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=3
SPRING_DATASOURCE_HIKARI_MAXIMUMPOOLSIZE=3
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for but could not find.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Answer (score 0):

There are valid and invalid properties, but Spring's `@ConfigurationProperties`, which used mostly for loading configurations, works with both forms of properties.

The issue can be if any framework, library, etc. use property separately, without `@ConfigurationProperties`. In this case, you will have runtime exception (or null value).

Most default, base, popular properties are here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html